# roughly but very finely carved

Tags: meaning

> The only other piece of furniture was a *bargueno*, elaborately
>   ornamented with gilt iron-work, on a stand of ecclesiastical design
>   roughly but very finely carved.
>
> Maugham, Somerset / Of Human Bondage

aren't these antonyms?

> roughly but very finely carved.

Answer (score 1):

"Fine" can be the opposite of "rough". But it can also mean "very good". So it is possible that the intent of the sentence was more like "roughly but very skillfully carved". It may be that the writer was deliberately making a play on words.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the usage. [Lexico's](https://www.lexico.com/definition/finely) entry for **finely** for this context is

> **1.1** In a manner worthy of or eliciting admiration.
>   *Miss Bingley was dressed very finely*

When used as an antonym of **roughly** it has this meaning

> **2.3** With delicate or intricate workmanship or structure.
>   *finely detailed mosaic pictures*

Comment: why did you choose Lexico as your dictionary?

Comment: Because I like it. It was The Oxford Dictionaries before it was rebranded.